# Why does this happen? HTML window width

Tags: html, css

I am experimenting with html markup and different layouts. I came across this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vLJAq/15/ which I played around with and tweaked a little. One thing I do not understand is, why does green box disappear when you make the window width smaller?

The code for the green box is as follows:

```
.percent {
    width:calc((100% - 400px)/1);
    background: lightgreen;
    border:1px solid grey;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.percent` disappears because the width of the window is lower than `400px`. The width is calculated by the full actual width of the window less the defined `400px`, so the minimum space to show the `.percent` is `401px`.

The `.percent` shows the width over `400px`. If your width of the windows is `410px` the `.percent` has a width of `10px`.

Comment: Is there a way to stop this from happening? I am trying to achieve a full page three column layout with the 1st and 3rd column fixed and the middle column adjust width according to screen size (much like in the example).