# Why is a `calc()` width with an illegal value not ignored?

Tags: css, css-calc

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41996221), I found this interesting phenomenon.

Since negative widths are illegal, and therefore should be ignored, I would expect style properties like `width:-200px;` and `width:calc(0% - 200px);` to have no effect. And indeed, for the first one it doesn't. The second one, however, is not ignored: a width of 0 is used instead.

See this example:

```css
div {border:1px solid; background:lime;}

#badwidth {width:-200px;}

#badcalc {width:calc(0% - 200px);}
```

```html
Div with bad width:
<div id="badwidth"> </div>

Div with bad calc:
<div id="badcalc"> </div>
```

If the width property was ignored, the div would be its full width (like the top one). However, it is collapsed to 0 (see the black line to the left; that's the border).

For reference, here are some other divs, to demonstrate 1) that `calc(0% - 200px)` by itself is not an error, and 2) that they work fine and the first snippet is an anomaly.

```css
div {border:1px solid; background:lime;}

#calc {margin-right:calc(0% - 200px);}
```

```html
Plain div:
<div> </div>

With calc(0% - 200px) in a place where it's OK:
<div id="calc"> </div>
```

So, why do normal widths and calculated widths behave differently?
If it was just one browser, I'd call it a bug. But they all treat this the same way! So there must be something I'm overlooking. What?

Comment: I hardly see this behavior as a bug or anomaly: I expect `width: calc(100% - 500px)` to result in a width of 0 at 500px _and below_; I'd be annoyed if width was back to default `auto` between 0 and 499px! :-) With your example of `0%`, we humans know that it'll never result in a positive value so yes it appears as a _strange_ behavior, but not with other examples imho. And CSS WG and browsers vendors have to account with many cases

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The evaluation of calc and the allowed values in a rule are different, as you are experiencing. According to the spec [CSS Values and Units](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#lengths):

> While some properties allow negative length values, this may complicate the formatting and there may be implementation-specific limits. If a negative length value is allowed but cannot be supported, it must be converted to the nearest value that can be supported.

In this case, `-200` is rounded up to `0` as it is the closest value supported for width.

**Edit**

The section before also states:

> Properties may restrict the length value to some range. If the value is outside the allowed range, the declaration is invalid and must be ignored.

When declaring `width: -200px`, this value is outside of the acceptable range, and is thus ignored. However, it seems `calc` evaluates -200 *before* the check occurs, and rounds it up to be within the acceptable range, so it is not ignored.

**Update**

Thanks to @CBroe for the [reference to the spec on calc](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#calc-range):

> Parse-time range-checking of values is not performed within calc(), and therefore out-of-range values do not cause the declaration to become invalid. However, the used value resulting from an expression must be clamped to the range allowed in the target context.
>
> Since widths smaller than 0px are not allowed, these three declarations are equivalent:

```
width: calc(5px - 10px);
width: calc(-5px);
width: 0px;
```

> Note however that width: -5px is not equivalent to width: calc(-5px)! Out-of-range values outside calc() are synactically invalid, and cause the entire declaration to be dropped.

Comment: If that were applicable, the value of `width:-200px` would _also_ be rounded up to 0. However, it is not, as you can see in the first example.

Comment: See my edit - `calc` must evaluate first before passing the final value to be checked against the rules for the property.

Comment: _“If that were applicable, the value of width:-200px would also be rounded up to 0”_ – nope, because width is a property that does not allow negative values in the first place - so right from the start, the first quoted sentence does not apply to width: _“While some properties allow negative length values, […]”_

Comment: For calc however it is explicitly specified here how it has to handle out-of-range values, https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#calc-range: _“Parse-time range-checking of values is not performed within calc(), and therefore out-of-range values do not cause the declaration to become invalid. However, the used value resulting from an expression must be clamped to the range allowed in the target context”_ - and that is what is happening here. calc gave a negative result, but for width that is not allowed - and so the resulting value is “clamped down” to 0.

Comment: @CBroe Wow. Can you post that as an answer, please?

Comment: Thanks for that explanation @CBroe, you stated that much clearer than I!

Comment: @MrLister: With chazsolo’s edit to the answer I think we got it covered. Just give him the upvote ;)

Comment: OK then. I must say I feel this post does take the long way round before actually mentioning the answer though ;)

Comment: If you'd prefer I'll rearrange the answer (or you can if you'd like). Let me know!